# Fill ListView from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'am facing a crash once I start to populate a ListView from my db by 
using simple CursorAdapter

and the logcat is showing this message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.osamawaosamawa.medcine/com.example.osamawaosamawa.medcine.ppllistViews}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

What is the _id column? I don't have this on that class

listview java class

```
public class ppllistViews extends Activity {
DB db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ppllistview);
    db=new DB(this);
    pupulatelistview();

  }

   public void pupulatelistview(){

    Cursor cursor = db.getpplNameData();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String [] pplinformation = new String[]{
            DB.col1T2
    };
    int [] maping = new int[]{
            R.id.PPLID
    };

    SimpleCursorAdapter mycursorAdapter =
            new    SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.pplnamelistxml,cursor,pplinformation,maping);


    ListView ppldatalistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewpplname);
    ppldatalistview.setAdapter(mycursorAdapter);
}
```

i already add this line in my DBCLASS

```
public final static  String colrowid = "_id";
```

my query, where can i add it here

```
  public Cursor getpplNameData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table_name2, null);
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CursorAdapters do need the `_id` column.

What you can do, is using the good old "rowID trick".
Simply add `, rowID AS _id` to your query to add the rowID and name it as `_id`.

So, if your query is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

change it to

```
SELECT *, rowID AS _id FROM ...
```

`rowID` is a hidden field which makes pretty much a substitute for the `_id` field.